# Aspect ratio of single cells

Tags: r, aspect-ratio

I would like to calculate the aspect ratio of cells using R.
I have the cells' area and diameter.
How would you find dmin and dmax?
Thanks in advance.

It should be a function of the largest diameter and the smallest diameter orthogonal to it: A = dmin/dmax. I would need an R code for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question whether you have the cells' maximum diameters, or minimum diameters, or both. However, if your cells can be assumed to be elliptical and you have measured them along either their long *or* short axis, then the following function will give you the aspect ratio from that single measurement and the area:

```r
aspect_ratio <- function(Area, Diameter) {
  round(pmin((4 / Diameter^2) * (Area / pi), (Diameter^2 / 4) * (pi / Area)), 3)
}
```

This follows from the geometrical formula for the area of an ellipse, which is simply `pi * dmax/2 * dmin/2`

To show this works, let us create 3 ellipses with known maximum and minimum diameters:

```r
library(sf)
library(nngeo)

dat <- data.frame(x = c(-5, 0, 5), y = 0, ex = c(2, 2, 2), ey = c(1, 2, 4)) |>
         st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"))

ellipses <- st_ellipse(pnt = dat, ex = dat$ex, ey = dat$ey, res = 1000)
plot(ellipses)
```

[image]

We can get the areas by direct measurement:

```r
st_area(ellipses)
#> [1]  6.283144 12.566288 25.132576
```

Now we can get their aspect ratios (defined as dmin/dmax) using our function, and only one diameter measurement for each ellipse:

```r
aspect_ratio(st_area(ellipses), Diameter = 2 * dat$ex)
#> [1] 0.5 1.0 0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>